# Add div inside div

Tags: jquery, html

I have generated html like this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="item google"></div>
   <div class="item mail"></div>
   <div class="item apps"></div>
   <div class="item plus"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="item google"></div>
   <div class="item mail"></div>
   <div class="item apps"></div>
   <div class="item plus"></div>
</div>
```

and I want to put other items inside google

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="item google">
     <div class="group">
       <div class="item mail"></div>
       <div class="item apps"></div>
       <div class="item plus"></div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="item google">
     <div class="group">
       <div class="item mail"></div>
       <div class="item apps"></div>
       <div class="item plus"></div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am creating group div:

```
jQuery("div.google").append('<div class="group"></div>');
```

but I when I do .append I adds all insted of

```
    jQuery("div.row > div.google > div.group").append(jQuery("div.mail"));
```

I have two divs with class mail. how to target only parent. Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/H6MYh/1/

Comment: why not just make a new div class?

Comment: Either work with IDs (unique) or select one element from your collection by adding an identifier (note the [0]): jQuery("div.row > div.google > div.group")[0].append(jQuery("div.mail"));

Comment: what do you mean? I dont have access on html, its generated I need to modify dom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following code:

```
jQuery("div.google").append('<div class="group"></div>');
jQuery("div.google").each(function(){
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    $this.siblings().appendTo($this.find('.group'));
});
```

EDIT:
for specific div:(not tested)

```
jQuery("div.google").each(function(){
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    $this.next('.mail').appendTo($this.find('.group'));
});
```

Comment: One more thing: if I want to specify div instad of $this.siblings() how do I do that?


   $('.mail').appendTo($this.find('.group'));

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wrapAll`.

```
$('div.row').each(function(){
     $('div:not(:first)', this).wrapAll('<div class="group"></div>')
})
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pfPvc/1/)

Comment: Right, but If I want to chose what div gets in group? eg. .mail and .apps and leave plus as it is?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("div.google")
```

gets all divs with class "google". To select only the first occurence, add [0] to it.

```
jQuery("div.google")[0].append('<div class="group"></div>');
jQuery("div.row > div.google > div.group").append(jQuery("div.mail"));
```

Comment: Instead of [0] try .eq(0) then: jQuery("div.row > div.google > div.group").eq(0).append(jQuery("div.mail"));​ - http://jsfiddle.net/H6MYh/3/

Answer (score 0):

You could use $(".row").each(...) to process each row in turn, then use .find(...) on the resultant objects to target only their children...